# Connecting a keyboard and trackpad to iPad Pro

Tags: ipad, keyboard, trackpad

This might look like a weird question so let me explain properly first.

I have built a special desk with a stand to hold an **iPad Pro**.
My problem is that when the iPad is inside the stand, it is at a perfect angle for the user to watch the content on the screen but it is not really in a good position be reached anymore.

*So I want to use a **wireless device** to use as keyboard and trackpad (mouse) from where I am sitting in order to interact with the iPad Pro.*

- I started by looking at the **Magic Keyboard + Magic Trackpad 2** but putting these two devices next to each other is unfortunately longer than the free space I have available on the desk. I tried to find a combined version of the Keyboard and Trackpad but I have not been able to find one that works wireless. (I am also not 100% sure that iPad Pro iOS is compatible to be used with Magic Keyboard and Trackpad)
- I have also tried to find out if another (smaller) iPad such as iPad mini or an iPhone can be used as a keyboard/trackpad to control the iPad Pro but I can not seem to find any answer online. Is this possible? or can a Apple TV2 remote be used to control an iPad Pro?

Does anyone know of a device that I could use to control the iPad Pro from a distance? (I need a device that does not stick out and goes well with the rest of the design, so please don't suggest an ugly Logitech keyboard)

***EDIT:***

I have now done some testing:

- **Magic Keyboard** could successfully be connected and used as a keyboard with the iPad Pro.
- **Trackpad 2** on the other hand would not connect to the iPad Pro. It would just not show up as a bluetooth device on the iPad Pro.

So I am still looking for a solution to control the iPad wirelessly.

Comment: I just tried connecting a gen1 Magic Trackpad to a 2018 iPad Pro yesterday and the iPad could not see it at all. BT works fine on it as I connected a keyboard & headphones, in addition to a Pencil.

I was able to pair with the trackpad on Windows too, so it appears to be an issue with the iPad.